# CoffeeScript Class PrivateMethod which uses instance property Issue

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I am currently working on CoffeeScript and encountered annoying issue.
When I make class privateMethod which is written as `privateMethod = ->` and If I want to use `@` a.k.a `this` property inside of the method, I get syntax error because of scope issue.
see the sample code below

```
class TestClass
  constructor : (@name = "NoName") ->
  privateFunc = ->
    console.log @name
  callPrivateFunc : ->
    privateFunc()

testClass = new TestClass("John")
testClass.callPrivateFunc() # @name is undefined
```

And I found 2 way to avoid the issue so far.

case 1 : use .call

```
class TestClass
  constructor : (@name = "NoName") ->
  privateFunc = ->
    console.log @name
  callPrivateFunc : ->
    privateFunc.call(this)

testClass = new TestClass("John")
testClass.callPrivateFunc() # "John"
```

case 2 : pass this arg as function param

```
class TestClass
  constructor : (@name = "NoName") ->
  privateFunc = (that)->
    console.log that.name
  callPrivateFunc : ->
    privateFunc(@)

testClass = new TestClass("John")
testClass.callPrivateFunc() # "John"
```

my question is, are these methods proper way to use a private method which uses `this`?
or is there any proper way/defacto standard?

Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 0):

As far as a 'proper' way, I don't think there is one. Using .call feels more correct to me. That's partially why .call exists. I would also take a look at Function.prototype.bind. It's used to bind a thisArg to a function. Take a look here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind.

.bind example:

```
class TestClass
  constructor : (@name = "NoName") -> privateFunc.bind(this)();
  privateFunc = ->
    alert @name

testClass = new TestClass("John") # alerts "John"
```

e; This is worth a read too: http://jsforallof.us/2014/07/08/var-that-this/.